# Add comment for using a python script?

Tags: python

Firstly, I don't know if there is some good rule or common practice for adding comments for usage of a Python script. 
Here is my question.

1. In a python script, with definition of functions, and the part below
   `if __name__ == '__main__':`, where shall I add the comment for
   usage of the part below `if __name__ == '__main__':`: on top of the
   script below the shebang, or below `if __name__ == '__main__':`?

   For example,

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python                             


   import argparse


   def myfun():
       ...

   if __name__ == '__main__':

       parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A script of writing comment of usage')
       parser.add_argument('--in', dest='in', help='an input file')
       parser.add_argument('--out', dest='out', help='an output file')
       args = parser.parse_args()
   ```

   My comment for usage of the part below `if __name__ == '__main__':`
   is an example of calling the script:

   ```
   ''' Example:                                                                                                                                                   
   myscript.py --in infile --out outfile
   '''
   ```

   where shall I add it in the script?
2. In comment for usage of the script, besides providing an example,
   what shall I also add? I think the options are self clear in the
   `parser.add_argument()`, and the purpose of the script is self clear
   in  `argparse.ArgumentParser()`?

   For example, from the above example,  are the following enough for
   explaining the purpose and options of the script?

   ```
       parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A script of writing comment of usage')

       parser.add_argument('--in', dest='in', help='an input file')
       parser.add_argument('--out', dest='out', help='an output file')
   ```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Standard Python module/script documentation is done as follows.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python 

"""
Leave your docs here. Describe the behaviour of your main function. E.g. 
The script does blah-blah... 
Standard usage: myscript.py --in infile --out outfile
"""

import ...
```

Along with that, you can modify the `help` argument in `argparse` to show standard usage. 
BTW, the `if __name__ == "__main__"` line is used in combination with a master function (it's usually called `main`). The point is to leave all the processing in the `main` function, e.g.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python  

"""
The script does blah-blah...
Standard usage: ...
"""

def foo(args...):
    ...

def ham(args...):
    ...

def main():
   # do something with foo and ham 

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: If create a function `main()`, shall I add its uage below `def main():`? Isn't its usage the same as the usage of the script?

Comment: You can add some specific pipeline information in the `main` function documentation, no need to repeat the standard usage example.

Comment: "add the --help argument in argparse to show standard usage". Isn't argparse has the --help argument by default? Do I have to add it explicitly?

Comment: What is the purpose of "leave all the processing in the main function"?

Comment: @Tim It leaves open the possibility of importing the script as a module without other side effects. The most common reason would be to make writing unit tests for the script easier.

Comment: @chepner: do you mean import the main() to other scripts?

Comment: In theory, you could. In practice, you would probably only import it into a test script for unit testing. You should primarily think of `main` as an entry point for executing other code in the module as a script.

Comment: Does main() take any parameter? If not, how can it get the command line arguments? @chepner

Comment: It can if you want to. There's nothing special about the name `main`, like in C. It's just a function you define in the module, then call from the `if` block.

Comment: @Tim `main` is mostly used without any parameters. In fact you should obtain command-line parameters using a function that returns all the parameters you need. The function (let it be `get_parameters`) itself can be written using `argparse` or `getopt` (I prefer the later).

Comment: @EliKorvigo: 
 
"add the --help argument in argparse to show standard usage". Isn't argparse has the --help argument by default? Do I have to add it explicitly?

Comment: @Tim it does, but I recommend you to manually specify the `usage` field in the `ArgumentParser` instance, e.g. `ArgumentParser(description="...", usage="write a more explicit usage line here")`

Comment: Isn't "ArgumentParser(description="...", usage="write a more explicit usage line here")" already in my code?

Comment: @Tim Not exactly. You do not specify the `usage` field manually, hence `argparse` will construct it automatically and it will look like `myscript.py [-h] [--in IN] [--out OUT]`. There is nothing wrong about it. Nevertheless, in your post you asked for a possibility to specify the following usage string  `myscript.py --in infile --out outfile`. This can be done as I mentioned in my previous message.

Comment: Do you mean `ArgumentParser(description="...", usage="Examples:/n myscript.py --in infile --out outfile")`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78224/discussion-between-eli-korvigo-and-tim).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using argparse (versus just adding comments), i recommend creating a `main` function at the top of your file. Put the comments there. Then, call `main()` inside the `if __name__ == "__main__` block.

That being aid, the common place to put comments is in a triple-quoted string at the very top, since that's the first thing people see when reading your code.

The bottom line isn you want to make your code easy to understand. Forcing the user to go looking for comments isn't making it easy.

Comment: What is the purpose of creating main(), and of calling main() inside the if __name__ == "__main__ block?

Comment: IMO it makes for cleaner, more maintainable code. Functionally there is no difference. Putting the definition of main at the top puts the highest-level logic at the start, making it (arguably) easier to understand the program.